# How to take screenshot with Phantomjs without blur

Tags: qt4, phantomjs

I'm using **PhantomJS** to convert HTML code to image.It work fine if the output is a png format but if I generate a jpg format ,the text in this image is blurred.Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with Qt or phantomjs. It's simply because of the image format.

**JPG** is a lossy compressed file format. Because of its implementation, it's useful for storing photographs. It is also a common choice for use on the Web because it is compressed. For storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a smaller file size, PNG or even GIF are better choices because they are lossless.

**PNG** format is a lossless compression file format, which makes it a common choice for use on the Web. PNG is a good choice for storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a small file size.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.In fact,I want to post this image on facebook,so is that possible to post it with PNG format without compression to JPG format?